# Can't print a number despite using str/int

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a noob trying to learn python 3 and I'm trying to include the half_age as a string without using directly writing the number 9 as a string but I couldn't figure it out.

I've tried:

```
print = str(18//2)
print = int(18//2)
print = float(18/2)

my_age = 18
half_age = (18//2)
name = "Kenny!"
greeting = "Kia Ora, "

print(greeting + name)

print("Your age is " + my_age + "and half your age is " + str(half_age ))
```

```
print("Your age is " + my_age + "and half your age is " + str(half_age ))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: Dont assign to variable named `print` - that's reserved for printing function. And convert `my_age` to string: `str(my_age)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! The problems are `my_age`, not `half_age`, which is still an `int` and overwriting the builtin `print` function. You may want to look into [string formatting](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting). Your `int()` and `float()` casts aren't necessary on lines 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting all of your numbers with `str` ie.

```py
my_age = 18
half_age = (18//2)
name = "Kenny!"
greeting = "Kia Ora, "

print(greeting + name)

print("Your age is " + str(my_age) + " and half your age is " + str(half_age))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Just use modern [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python):

```
my_age = 18
half_age = (18//2)
name = "Kenny"
greeting = "Kia Ora"


print(f'{greeting}, {name}!')
print(f"Your age is {my_age} and half your age is {half_age}")
```

or

```
print(f"Your age is {my_age} and half your age is {my_age/2}")
```

Comment: Since Python 3.6... for lower versions use the similar `format` method